# my Italic font vim iTerm2 on mac not working

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2, italic, osx-yosemite

I am having trouble implementing italic style in my Vim under iTerm2 on OS X Yosimite.

I did the step-by-step from https://alexpearce.me/2014/05/italics-in-iterm2-vim-tmux/ and my iTerm is able to render italic.
But my Vim still not working.

I've set the font to **Menlo** which has italic style supported and when i set the comment to italic in vim:

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic
```

The comment become having a bg-color instead of italic.
[image: Italic style not rendering properly]

Do you guys know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the issue with my italic font not rendering properly. Tha was completly my own mistake. 
I have **term** set in my **vimrc** to **xterm-256** instead of using whatever the terminal/iterm2 has.